# Will I get two server request on an image if I append the img tag on two components?

Tags: html, angular, src

I need to download an image on one component (which will be through `<img src="path">`) and send it to another component. I'm thinking of using a service to communicate and append an `<img src="path">` tag to the second components template.

I'm not sure what happens under the hood and want to confirm if the browser will download the img again if I append the tag or know if this is the right way to send image data in Angular.

How can I pass a down the same image to another component and make sure I'm not requesting the resource again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `img` tag is fully managed by your browser, meaning that you don't have control over its behavior.

That being said, the browser is supposed to have a cache system, so if you request twice the same image AND the server's response is `304 (Not Modified)` the browser is supposed to use the cache.

If you want to make sure that you have a cached image, you can implement your own `img` wrapping component that would `GET` the image, create a blob from it and inject it in an `img` component, this way you can cache the image blob by yourself in a dedicated service.